# Make controller only give a value to template, not render it - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a twig template with the navbar and all other templates (the pages) include this template. I have a value in it which should be equal to all pages. How to set this value?

I tries something like this in a controller:

```
public function setNotificationsAction() {
    $this->setNotifications();
    return $this->render('AcmeMyBundle::navbar.html.twig', array(
        'debts' => $this->notifications,
    ));
}
```

and then this in the template:

```
<span class="badge badge-important">
    {% render(controller('AcmeMyBundle:DebtsLoansController:setNotifications')) %}
    {{ debts }}
</span>
```

The result I want it like this:

```
<span class="badge badge-important">
    3
</span>
```

but the number should be different and the controller should tell it.

I also tried to create a function which returns the value and to call it in the way like above.

I also tried this syntax

`{{ render(controller('AcmeMyBundle:DebtsLoansController:setNotifications')) }}`

but it isn't working, too.

I get the following mistake:

`The function "controller" does not exist in AcmeMyBundle::navbar.html.twig at line 6`

Do you have any idea how to achive this and not to have to edit each controller and each template :S Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would suggest creating your own Twig extension. Something around the lines of:

```
<span class="badge">
    {{ acme_notifications() }}
</span>
```

```php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeDemoExtension

class AcmeDemoExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'acme_notifications' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getNotifications');
        );
    }

    public function getNotifications()
    {
        $notifications = ...;

        return $notifications;
    }
}
```

Read more about creating your own Twig extension in [the Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the controller part :

```
{% render "AcmeBundle:MyController:MyAction" %}
```

Be aware however, that a `render` is a completely new request going through the whole Symfony lifecycle and thus can impact performance if you abuse it.

Edit : And as @Wouter J has pointed out : prior to Symfony 2.2 use above notation. After Symfony 2.2 the following has to be used :

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles', { 'max': 3 })) }}
```

Comment: Now the error is `A block must start with a tag name in AcmeBudgetTrackerBundle::navbar.html.twig at line 6` :( It there any better solution to the problem? I don't want it exactly that way, but this was the only one I could come up with.

Comment: as of Symfony 2.2, you need the controller function and you need to use the render function instead of the render tag

Comment: @Faery That is an error in your template. You must have an `extend` and a `block` element without a name.